# Confining an IDW interpolation to a polygon in R{Spatstat}

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I'm a fairly new R user working with spatial data for places embedded within US metro areas.  I'm working on generating IDW maps for a number of variables and am having trouble defining the boundaries of the IDW.  I would like to interpolate data only within the confines of the metro area boundary, while my current approach fills the entire plot.

I begin by creating a `ppp` object from a `dataframe` as such:

```
x.points<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords =x.data[,c("LON10","LAT10")],
  data=x.data[,c("v1","v2")],
  proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs"))

x.proj<-spTransform(x.points,CRSobj = CRS("+proj=aea
  +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 
  +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"))    

x.ppp<-as.ppp(x.proj)
```

Projecting this `ppp` object  using `plot(x.ppp)` displays a plot for each of the variables ("v1" and "v2" in the code above).  However, the plot fills the entire rectangular frame.  I limit this frame when plotting my `ppp` object by assigning an `owin` object to it, as follows:

```
y.spdf<-spTransform(y.spdf,CRSobj = CRS("+proj=aea 
  +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 
  +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

y.owin<-as.owin(y.spdf)

x.ppp<-x.ppp[y.owin]
```

Plotting this using `plot(x.ppp)` now gives me a plot of my data points correctly framed within the polygon of their metro area.  While this is a good start, I want to continue to pass this spatial frame onto an IDW map.  Consulting the spatstat handbook leads me to believe that I could pass my `owin` object as an `as.mask` argument, but whenever I do, I get an error.  Example code follows:

```
idw<-idw(x.ppp, power=4, as.mask(y.owin))
```

This gives me the error "Error in switch(at, pixels = { : EXPR must be a length 1 vector".  Using `at="points"` does not work, as I instead get a resulting `dataframe` object rather than an `imlist`.  If I leave out the `as.mask` argument I get a correct idw, but it interpolates beyond the metro area boundaries that I was previously able to set using the `owin` object.

I figure this is a fairly common task, but consuting the spatstat documentation left me at a bit of a loss.  The `as.mask` argument seems like it would work, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Any input or advice on how to solve this problem, or a source to which I could turn to try and better understand the issue would be a great help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see how this is a bit confusing. Basically `idw` calculates the result in the entire rectangular box containing the data (the frame of the `owin`).
This is the result you get if you do `rslt <- idw(x.ppp)`. To restrict the result to the polygonal window we need to subset the resulting image by this window (and set `drop=FALSE` to get the resulting irregular image rather than the pixel values inside the polygonal region). Explained in code:

### Simple case (one numeric mark value)

```
library(spatstat)
# Fake data with one numeric mark
X <- humberside
marks(X) <- runif(npoints(X))
# Window is a polygonal region:
W <- Window(X)
W
# IDW in the frame of W
rslt <- idw(X)
# Subset of IDW inside W
rslt <- rslt[W, drop = FALSE]
plot(rslt)
```

[image: IDW for one variable]

### Multivariate case (two or more numeric mark values)

```
library(spatstat)
# Fake data with more numeric marks
X <- humberside
marks(X) <- cbind(x = runif(npoints(X)), y = runif(npoints(X)))
# Window is a polygonal region:
W <- Window(X)
W
# IDW in the frame of W for each mark variable (imlist object)
rslt <- idw(X)
# Subset of IDW inside W for each mark variable (imlist object)
rslt <- solapply(rslt, "[.im", W, drop = FALSE)
plot(rslt)
```

[image: IDW for two variables]